# union of different vectors at each iteration in matlab

Tags: matlab, union

Pseudocode:

```
for each iteration i
    select n vectors from a matrix's columns (say:1,5,7 for n=3) based on a rule
    united=union(mat(:,1),mat(:,5),mat(:,7))
    ...do some stuff.
    Update n based on a rule
next i
```

As you can see, my `n` value changes over time. And the vectors which are going to `union()`, change also. I couldn't find any way to get union of vectors which are changes over time. Any solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumed that `n` updates randomly any you want to extract `n` columns randomly so you can use `unique` function to get unique values from those columns.

```
r = 5;
c = 7;
mat= rand(r,c);
for i = 1:10
    %update n randomly
    n = randi(c);
    %generate indexes of n columns randomly
    idx = randperm(c,n);
    %set union of selected columns
    united = unique(mat(:,idx));
end
```